# XLOOKUP to Index Match or something pre Office 365

Tags: microsoft-excel

I desperately need to convert this XLOOKUP

```
=XLOOKUP(D10;XLOOKUP(D8;D12:G12;D14:G24;;-1);C14:C24;;-1)
```

to an INDEX MATCH or something that works without O365. The job deadline is super soon and I cant get it to work.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your data and preferably some sample data and a more detailed description of the problem and desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(C14:C24,  IFERROR(  MATCH(D10,    INDEX(D14:G24,,  IFERROR(  MATCH(D8,D12:G12,0),  MATCH(D8,D12:G12,1)  )),0),    MATCH(D10,  INDEX(D14:G24,,  IFERROR(  MATCH(D8,D12:G12,0),  MATCH(D8,D12:G12,1)  )),1)  ))
```

What you want is pretty straightforward with one exception. For the straightforward part, `XLOOKUP()` is based on the `INDEX/MATCH` technique so it converts perfectly ordinarily. Yours has the complication of looking for a header, horizontally, then using that to find the value in the C column. Still, standard stuff. Anyone writing this can write the other, and easily.

So, I figure your block is in the one exception:  the match_mode parameter of `XLOOKUP()`, that "-1" at the end. The place that converts into is the match_type parameter of `MATCH()` which is a somewhat different type. With `XLOOKUP()` the relevant values are `<=`, `=`, and `>=` while `MATCH()` uses `"<"` (less than ONLY), `=`, and `>`.

Probably many ways to overcome that, but I used a really simple "this or that" approach in the above formula with `IFERROR()` discerning which to use since if one fails, it errors out making `IFERROR()` a natural here.

The formula does the match looking for an exact match to D8 first, and if it succeeds, that's what's fed forward. If it fails, it looks for the less than match which actually returns not just any less than match, or the first one, but rather the closest to without going over one. Which meets the need of matching `XLOOKUP()`'s behavior.

And the same thing in the second use of `MATCH()` as your original formula wants `<=` here as well.

A shame that the `Xxxx()` family of functions all came out at the same time as `XMATCH()` uses the the same match_mode parameters that `XLOOKUP()` does. But if one has not the one, one has not the other so...

So, inelegant looking, and kind of a plodding chunker, but it does the trick. And there's nothing in it that won't run in versions down to at least 2007 when `IFERROR()` began its career. Below that, just wrap the exact matching in an `ISERROR()` and place it as the test in an `IF()`. Use the not-exact match attempt as the second (the `ISERROR()` was TRUE because it did error) parameter and the exact match then as the third parameter (the `ISERROR()` was FALSE, so the `IF()` was FALSE). `ISERROR()` will take you down the version trail to at least Excel for Windows 2 because I started with Excel there and it was something I learned early.

Again though, surely several other ways to do this. But this works and your time is short, so... something to consider.